# Markdown code highlighting to distinguish output from input

Tags: python, markdown, jekyll

I am using `.md` files to write Jekyll posts and want to distinguish `python` code returned output from regular code.

So for example, `df.columns` would return a long list which I want to highlight also with a different code highlight style so the reader can distinguish codes from their return values.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Python interpreter uses `>>>` as a prompt; in many cases you can use this to indicate input:

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
```

This should work out of the box with Jekyll:

```
{% highlight python %}
>>> 1 + 2
3
{% endhighlight %}
```